# Unable to access BIOS in RV409 via HDMI

Tags: laptop, bios, hdmi

So I have a RV409 laptop which has Windows 8.1 installed currently and I'm unable to access the BIOS Setup menu from my HDMI display. I can get the Windows OS output from my RV409 to my HDMI Display. Is there a way to get BIOS menu displaying on my HDMI display?

Answer (score 0):

Your Bios Setup display (menu) may only be provided to you via hardware that is supported to your through your firmware.

Do you get the bios on your monitor?

Comment: I forgot to tell something, RV409 is a laptop and it's lid is completely removed from the laptop, plus I'm unable to get the BIOS menu output

Comment: are you holding the F9 key during boot to access your BIOS?

Comment: Yes, but I'm unable to get the output